# Select Case for Number Formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Having an issue executing the following code to apply appropriate number formatting for a selected cell range. A type mismatch error keeps occurring on the first case statement. I'm sure it is a simple error - some advice would be appreciated.

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Selection
Select Case cell.NumberFormat

Case "$#,##0.0_);($#,##0.0);"" - -""_);@_)":

cell.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0_);(#,##0.0);"" - -""_);@_)"
```

Comment: Guessing it's the " - -". This has been fixed - but the format is not being actively changed upon execution.

Comment: Yeah you need to double up quotes within a string. Can you [edit] your question with the current fixed code?

Comment: @BigBen edited. Any clue on why the number format would not be changing upon execution?

Comment: What's the difference between the original number format and the new one?

Comment: Absence of dollar sign.

Comment: Ha, of course, my oversight  - Why don't you add a `Debug.print cell.NumberFormat` and see if the `Case` even is true. The code works for me on test data (removes the dollar sign).

Comment: Also make sure the value is an actual number and not text that looks like the number format.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to make it running correctly:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A3")
        'Debug.Print myCell.NumberFormat
        Select Case myCell.NumberFormat
            Case Is = "#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)":
                Debug.Print "some number"
            Case Else
                Debug.Print myCell.NumberFormat
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

The tricky part is coming exactly with the correct number formatting. To do this, make the format in an Excel cell, select the cell and write in the immediate window `?Selection.NumberFormat`. Then copy it and put it between `"`:

[image]

Comment: @PGSystemTester - Camtasia.

Comment: @PGSystemTester [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) is another option.